# SQL: Join fact on dimension using bridge table and return concatenated list for column of interest

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I would like to join multiple dimension tables to a fact table. However, instead of returning all the results, I want to avoid a one-to-many relationship result. Instead, I would like to access just *some* of the data in one table, concatenate all of its findings, and return them into a single column so that the expected result of 1 row per fact remains. I do not want a one-to-many relationship in my result.

If I pair this answer [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv/42778050#42778050) with additional columns of interest, I get an error, saying: `is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

```
-- sample values
-- bridge
dim2Key, groupKey
1,          1
2,          1
3,          1
4,          2

-- dim2
dim2Key, attributeOne
1,      'A'
2,      'B'
3,      'C'
4,      'A'

-- dim1
dim1Key, attributeTwo, attributeThree,
1,      35,                  'val1'      
2,      25,                  'val2'   
3,      45,                  'val3'   
4,      55,                  'val1'   

-- fact1
dim1Key, factvalue1, groupKey,
1,        5,            1
2,        25,           1
3,        55,           -1
4,        99,           2


-- expected values
-- fact1
dim1Key, factvalue1, groupKey, attributeTwo, attributeThree, attributeOne
1,          5,          1,          35,         'val1',         'A, B, C'
...
4,          99,         2,           55,         'val1',            'A'
```

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result, please.

Comment: Updated to accommodate expected data/results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unclear what your schema and joins should be, but it seems you want to aggregate `dim2` per row of `fact1`.

You can aggregate `dim2` inside a correlated subquery. It's often nicer to put this in an `APPLY` but you could also put it directly in the `SELECT`

```
SELECT
  fact1.dim1Key,
  fact1.factvalue1,
  fact1.groupKey,
  dim1.attributeTwo,
  dim1.attributeThree,
  dim2.attributeOne
FROM fact1
JOIN dim1 ON dim1.dim1key = fact1.dim1key
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT attributeOne = STRING_AGG(dim2.attributeOne, ', ')
    FROM bridge b
    JOIN dim2 ON dim2.dim2key = b.dim2key
    WHERE b.groupKey = fact1.groupKey
) dim2
```

Comment: Wow, I kneel. This is incredible and precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the STRING_AGG function in your version of SQL, you can use FOR XML PATH to achieve the same thing.

```
    CREATE TABLE #bridge (dim2Key int, groupKey int)
    INSERT  #bridge (dim2Key, groupKey) 
    VALUES (1, 1)
    ,(2, 1)
    ,(3, 1)
    ,(4, 2)

    CREATE TABLE #dim2 (dim2Key int, attributeOne varchar(5))
    INSERT  #dim2 (dim2Key, attributeOne)
    VALUES (1, 'A')
    ,(2, 'B')
    ,(3, 'C')
    ,(4, 'A')

    CREATE TABLE #dim1 (dim1Key int, attributeTwo int, attributeThree varchar(5))
    INSERT #dim1 (dim1Key, attributeTwo, attributeThree)
    VALUES (1, 35,   'val1') 
    ,(2, 25,   'val2')   
    ,(3, 45,   'val3')   
    ,(4, 55,   'val1')   

    CREATE TABLE #fact1 (dim1Key int, factvalue1 int, groupKey int)
    INSERT #fact1 (dim1Key, factvalue1, groupKey)
    VALUES (1,   5,  1)
    ,(2,   25, 1)
    ,(3,   55, -1)
    ,(4,   99, 2)
    GO
    

    ;WITH pvt (groupKey, attributeOne)
    AS 
    (
        SELECT b.groupKey, d2.attributeOne 
        FROM #dim2 d2
        JOIN #bridge b
        ON d2.dim2Key = b.dim2Key
    )
    , dim2 AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.groupKey
        ,LEFT(r.attributeOne.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') , LEN(r.attributeOne.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'))-1) attributeOne 
        FROM pvt a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT attributeOne + ', '
            FROM pvt r
            WHERE a.groupKey = r.groupKey
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) r (attributeOne)
    )



    SELECT f1.dim1Key, factvalue1, f1.groupKey, attributeTwo, attributeThree, attributeOne 
    FROM #fact1 f1
    LEFT JOIN #dim1 d1
    ON f1.dim1Key = d1.dim1Key
    LEFT JOIN dim2 d2
    ON f1.groupKey = d2.groupKey
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough way of going about this -- to include an alternate pathway and the work of establishing dummy data -- very thoughtful work and help!